# Streaming downloads from SharePoint

Tags: media-streaming

Got an interesting question today that I was unable to answer.  Has anyone seen or developed a good solution for streaming the upload/download of large files in SharePoint? The ideal solution would be similar to the Microsoft File Transfer Manager that is based on BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service).  Has anyone done BITS work with SharePoint?

Optionally, is there a PDF viewer web part that would allow the first pages of the PDF to display as they are downloaded so that the user does not have to wait for 600 pages to download before viewing any of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to look at the [Silverlight Multi File Uploader](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/) project. I can't vouch for it, but a colleague informs me that it splits a file to upload into small chunks and transfers each "chunk" to SharePoint. Even shows progress apparently.

Comment: @RobWilson were you successful in using this for download as the answer only mentions uploads. If so any cues how to do streaming downloads?